# Incorrect number of dimensions error with bootstrap method using R

Tags: r, statistics, bootstrapper, statistics-bootstrap, sample-data

I am a newbie in programming with R, and trying to reproduce the values from research paper (Eur. Phys. J. C (2022) 82:1106 https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-022-11071-9), where the maximum frequency values (MFV) statistic has been applied. The authors used bootstrap method to estimate confidence interval for MFV (see page 5 of the paper). Unfortunately, I have stuck with application of bootstrap.

I have prepared a minimum working example that reproduce the problem. Thank you in advance.
Victor

Addition:

Found solution to bootstrapping here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-find-bootstrap-confidence-interval-in-r

Thank you all who responded to original question.

Comment: Please contemplate what _minimal_ might mean in minimal working example and focus your code on the real problem. Also remove unnecessary code. I think we can expect that little effort from you.

Comment: Simplified original R-script...
Still fighting with error